# how to link drive with laravel 10 and how to avoid error code: 401

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-developers-console

in my file sys file

```
'driver' => 'google',
'clientId' => env("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"),
'clientSecret' => env("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"),
'refreshToken' => env("GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN"),
'folderId' => env("GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID"),
```

and i try to upload an simple image to the account I have sign in with in

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=****

then why i take that error

`code: 401,  Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.  See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" } ], status "UNAUTHENTICATED",  details [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": { "method": "google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.Create", "service": "drive.googleapis.com`

i try to use the drive as a storage in laravel 10

Comment: please include [example] there isnt enough code here to recreate your issue you haven't shown us how you are authenticating or how you're sending the request